# Less has finished and no sheets were loaded

Tags: html, css, less

I'm developing a website using LESS and I can't seem to get it working. I just keep getting the following message:

> Less has finished and no sheets were loaded.

I'm running on a http-server web server to see the effect of the less and my Chrome Console has no errors or 404's etc. The code I have in place is super basic as I'm just testing for the time being. Only thing I can think it might be is a script ordering issue or maybe a conflict?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TrakMan | Re-Brand | Version 1</title>

         <!-- LESS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Styles and Fonts -->
        <!-- Font Import -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Trakman Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- JS SCripts -->
        <!-- JQuery CDN -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Font Awesome CDN-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c704ae342d.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

variables.less:

```
// Colours
@primary: #F86301;
@primary-light: #FF8C3A;
@primary-lighter: #FFA564;
@primary-dark: #C75200;
@primary-darker: #9C4100;
@dark: #222;
@light: #E7E7E7;

// Fonts
@family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
@size: 14px;
```

styles.less:

```
@import "variables.less";

html {
    font-family: @family;
    font-size: @size;
}

body {
    background: @dark;
}
```

Comment: You need a preprocessor to generate css based on your less file.

Comment: [Client-side Usage](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage): "Make sure you include your stylesheets *before* the script".

Comment: Thanks that fixed it :)